# Make Header of docked items Visible / Collapsed on a button click

Tags: wpf, devexpress-wpf

Please help me to make the header of the docked items visible/collapsed based on a buttonclick.

I tried `ShowCaption=false;`
but it didn't work.

XAML:

```
<Border x:Name="_mainBorder" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Gray"  Margin="5,5,5,5"  Grid.Row="1" >
    <Grid  Name="_mainGrid">
        <dxdo:DockLayoutManager Background="Gray"  dxdo:RestoreLayoutOptions.RemoveOldPanels="False" Name="dockManager1">
            <dxdo:LayoutGroup  ShowCaption="False" Background="Black" x:Name="RootGroup" >

                <!--region #1-->
                <dxdo:DocumentGroup Background="Black" x:Name="documentGroup1" >

                </dxdo:DocumentGroup>
                <!--endregion #1-->

            </dxdo:LayoutGroup>
        </dxdo:DockLayoutManager>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

Code Behind:

```
documentGroup1.Add(dts);
documentGroup1.Add(outPut);
documentGroup1.Add(pie);
documentGroup1.Add(serialNoWindow);
documentGroup1.Add(station);
documentGroup1.Add(testTime);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you raise the query to **DevExpress** support?because in version 15 they come up with many bug fixes.